# Displaying mvc object in Dojo DGrid

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor, dojo

Hi All looking for some help. I am new to using Dojo this is my first try
I hava a data call that returns a list of objects. I cant get it to display more than one record at a time. The grid header renders but no data if I try to load more than one object.  Here is the Code. I am not sure what I am doing wrong.  Been working on this for a week now. someone please help. What am I doing wrong.

data looks like this 
the raw view looks like this

"{\"FSC\":\"195\",\"IINSGM\":\"12345\",\"MMAC\":\"GG\",\"ISMASTER\":\"12345\",\"ItemName\":\"ECU(801A)\",\"ALC\":\"W\",\"WING\":\" SCMW\",\"GROUP\":\"SCMG\",\"SQUADRON\":\"SCMS\",\"DIR\":\"LM\",\"DIV\":\"Y\"

there is actually I think ten lines like this there will be more later.

```
  <script>


//var data = [];

@* @foreach(System.Web.Mvc.JsonResult s in Model)
{
    @:data.push('@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(s))');
}*@

@*getData();
function getData() {
    var actionResult = '@Url.Action("Report","Alc")';
    $.getJSON(actionResult, loadData);
}
function loadData(responce) {
    if (responce != null) {
        for (var i = 0 ; i < responce.length; i++) {
            data.push(responce[i]);

        }
    }
}*@

@*var model = '@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model))'.;
var data = [];
$.each(model.Data, function () {
    data.push($(this));
});*@ // all above this point i tried and they didn't work

var data = '@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model))';// this works with one record
var myStore, dataStore, grid;
myStore = JSON.parse(data).Data;

require([
'dstore/Memory',
'dgrid/OnDemandGrid',
'dojo/_base/declare',
'dgrid/ColumnSet'
], function (Memory, OnDemandGrid, declare, ColumnSet)
{

    var CustomGrid = declare([OnDemandGrid, ColumnSet]);
    var data = [
  {
    FSC: myStore.FSC,
    IINSGM: myStore.IINSGM,
    ISMaster: myStore.ISMASTER,
    ItemName: myStore.ItemName,
    MMAC: myStore.MMAC,
    ALC: myStore.ALC,
    WING: myStore.WING,
    GROUP: myStore.GROUP,
    SQUADRON: myStore.SQUADRON,
    DIR: myStore.DIR,
    DIV: myStore.DIV,
    IMS: myStore.IMS,
    ES: myStore.ES,
    PMSBUYER: myStore.PMSBUYER,
    PMSSELLER: myStore.PMSSELLER,
    ERRC: myStore.ERRC,
    ITEMCAT: myStore.ITEMCAT,
    ALT: myStore.ALT,
    PLT: myStore.PLT,
    SMC: myStore.SMC,
    ItmDefDispossalCode: myStore.ItmDefDispossalCode,
    ItmDefDispossalLevel: myStore.ItmDefDispossalLevel,
    ItmDefDispossalSRCCo: myStore.ItmDefDispossalSRCCode,
    DEMIC: myStore.DEMIC,
    ItemActivityCD: myStore.ItemActivityCD,
    SecurityCode: myStore.SecurityCode,
    BP: myStore.BP,
    NextHigherAssembly: myStore.NextHigherAssembly,
    UnitPrice: myStore.UnitPrice,
    FUP: myStore.FUP,
    WTURC: myStore.WTURC,
    BuyQtyCy: myStore.BuyQtyCy,
    BuyDollars: myStore.BuyDollars,
    ORWM: myStore.ORWM,
    BuyQtyAY: myStore.BuyQtyAY,
    BuyDollarsAY: myStore.BuyDollarsAY,
    BuyQTR: myStore.BuyQTR,
    BuyDollars: myStore.BuyDollars,
    RepairQtyCy: myStore.RepairQtyCy,
    RepairDollCy: myStore.RepairDollCy,
    RepairQtyAy: myStore.RepairQtyAy,
    RepairDollAy: myStore.RepairDollAy,
    RepairQty: myStore.RepairQty,
    RepairDoll: myStore.RepairDoll,
    ExcessQty: myStore.ExcessQty,
    ExcessDollar: myStore.ExcessDollar,
    TermQty: myStore.TermQty,
    TermDollar: myStore.TermDollar,
    NetAsset: myStore.NetAsset,
    Rate: myStore.Rate,
    PastConds: myStore.PastConds,
    futureConds: myStore.futureConds,
    CondsPerYr: myStore.CondsPerYr,
    YrsOfSupply: myStore.YrsOfSupply,
    SummaryType: myStore.SummaryType
}
];
    grid = new CustomGrid({
    collection: new Memory({ data: data }),

    columnSets: [
            [
                [
                    { label: "FSC", field: "FSC", width: "34px" },
                    { label: "SGM NIIN", field: "IINSGM", width: "74px" },
                    { label: "I & S Master", field: "ISMaster", width: "95px" },
                    { label: "Item Name", field: "ItemName", width: "90px" }
]
], [
                [
                    { label: "MMAC", field: "MMAC", width: "55px" },
                    { label: "ALC", field: "ALC", width: "40px" },
                    { label: "Wing", field: "WING", width: "50px" },
                    { label: "Group", field: "GROUP", width: "50px" },
                    { label: "Squadron", field: "SQUADRON", width: "75px" },
                    { label: "DIR", field: "DIR", width: "30px" },
                    { label: "DIV", field: "DIV", width: "30px" },
                    { label: "IMS", field: "IMS", width: "30px" },
                    { label: "ES", field: "ES", width: "30px" },
                    { label: "PMS Buyer", field: "PMSBUYER", width: "85px" },
                    { label: "PMS Seller", field: "PMSSELLER", width: "85px" },
                    { label: "ERRC", field: "ERRC", width: "50px" },
                    { label: "ItemCat", field: "ITEMCAT", width: "60px" },
                    { label: "ALT", field: "ALT", width: "40px" },
                    { label: "PLT", field: "PLT", width: "40px" },
                    { label: "SMC", field: "SMC", width: "40px" },
                    { label: "Item Def Disposal Code", field: "ItmDefDispossalCode", width: "140px" },
                    { label: "Item Def Disposal Level", field: "ItmDefDispossalLevel", width: "140px" },
                    { label: "Item Def Disposal SRC Code", field: "ItmDefDispossalSRCCo", width: "140px" },
                    { label: "DEMIL", field: "DEMIC", width: "50px" },
                    { label: "Item Activity Cd", field: "ItemActivityCD", width: "120px" },
                    { label: "Security Code", field: "SecurityCode", width: "120px" },
                    { label: "BP", field: "BP", width: "30px" },
                    { label: "Next Higher Assembly", field: "NextHigherAssembly", width: "120px" },
                    { label: "Unit Price", field: "UnitPrice", width: "75px" },
                    { label: "FUP", field: "FUP", width: "40px" },
                    { label: "WT URC", field: "WTURC", width: "70px" },
                    { label: "Buy Qty(CY)", field: "BuyQtyCy", width: "100px" },
                    { label: "Buy Dollars(CY)", field: "BuyDollars", width: "125px" },
                    { label: "OWRM", field: "ORWM", width: "55px" },
                    { label: "Buy Qty(AY)", field: "BuyQtyAY", width: "100px" },
                    { label: "Buy Dollars(AY)", field: "BuyDollarsAY", width: "125px" },
                    { label: "Buy Qty", field: "BuyQTR", width: "90px" },
                    { label: "Buy Dollars", field: "BuyDollars", width: "90px" },
                    { label: "Repair Qty(CY)", field: "RepairQtyCy", width: "120px" },
                    { label: "Repair Dollars(CY)", field: "RepairDollCy", width: "145px" },
                    { label: "Repair Qty(AY)", field: "RepairQtyAy", width: "120px" },
                    { label: "Repair Dollars(AY)", field: "RepairDollAy", width: "145px" },
                    { label: "Repair Qty", field: "RepairQty", width: "90px" },
                    { label: "Repair Dollars", field: "RepairDoll", width: "120px" },
                    { label: "Excess Qty", field: "ExcessQty", width: "90px" },
                    { label: "Excess Dollars", field: "ExcessDollar", width: "120px" },
                    { label: "Term Qty", field: "TermQty", width: "80px" },
                    { label: "Term Dollars", field: "TermDollar", width: "100px" },
                    { label: "Net Assets", field: "NetAsset", width: "100px" },
                    { label: "Rate", field: "Rate", width: "50px" },
                    { label: "Past Conds", field: "PastConds", width: "20px" },
                    { label: "Future Conds", field: "futureConds", width: "20px" },
                    { label: "Conds per Year", field: "CondsPerYr", width: "20px" },
                    { label: "Years of Supply", field: "YrsOfSupply", width: "20px" },
                    { label: "Summary Type", field: "SummaryType", width: "20px" }
        ]
    ]
],
    loadingMessage: 'Loading data...',
    noDataMessage: 'No results found.',
}, 'grid');
    grid.startup();


});
```

```
    <div id="grid" class="dgrid dgrid-grid ui-widget grid dgrid-autoheight"    style="height: 400px; width: auto; margin: 10px;">

</div>
```

here is the controller

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Report(FilterModelBig model)
    {
        //run the report program 
        AlcReportBuilder250 report = new AlcReportBuilder250();
        var data = report.BuildReport(model);

        //return View(Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet)); this is what I need it does not work

        return View(Json(data[0], JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet)); // this works
    }
```

I have 10 records to display it could be up to a 1000 later  any advice would be great !

Comment: can you provide an extract of ```data``` ? Maybe create a working snippets ?

Comment: @ben I provided a snippet of the data any thoughts

Comment: you way of creating store is very strange, why do you use a cache store of a JSonRest store if you data are already there ? Whay do you pass the data to the restStore ? target is supposed to be an URL. Also, your data are not formatted as a store expect. You should start by reading this: https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/quickstart/data/usingdatastores/simple.html#quickstart-data-usingdatastores-simple

Comment: @ben I have posted the new code from today tried several things. I read that page but I also read in the grid section the grid would recognize JSON. All the alerts from this version work and show the correct thing and at the end it looks like properly formatted JSON data. it still won't bind to the grid.